# Конструкция "как мне кажется"

Tags: вводные-слова

Эта вводная конструкция — что-то новомодное? Раньше так разве говорили? Бывает, поддамся этому веянию и сам так скажу иногда, но внутри ощущение того, что это *"не очень по-русски"* получается.

Или я во всём ошибаюсь?

***Добавление:***

Меня уже убедили, что так говорить нормально и так говорили всегда, но всё же остаются сомнения, абсолютно ли безупречно, если этот оборот стоит в начале фразы? Я нашёл и в Нацкорпусе такие примеры по подсказке Сибиллы, но всё-таки не было примеров от величайших, самых знаменитых писателей (чтобы именно в начале стояло). Я понимаю, что даже в начале употребить не будет ошибкой, но всё же мне кажется, что, ***возможно,*** в большинстве случаев есть какая-то лучшая замена этому выражению, если оно придётся на начало (напр., "Мне кажется, что...").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(на вторую часть вопроса)

Думаю, что допустимо так сказать и в начале предложения: это ненавязчивая *ссылка* на собственное *сложившееся* мнение. Когда ссылаются на других, говорят примерно так же: "Как сказал (бы) такой-то, ...". В отличие от выражения "Мне кажется, что..." слова "Как мне кажется, ..." подчёркивают, что мнение (возможно, и ошибочное, раз "кажется"), которое высказывается, не в ответ на реплику собеседника возникло, а сформировалось раньше (мол, я об этом уже думал и опираюсь на мнение, которое у меня сложилось). Не всякий собеседник уловит эту разницу в оттенках, но вероятно, говорящий интуитивно подразумевает именно это, делая выбор в пользу одного из таких выражений - если сам он разборчив, а не просто произносит привычный ему штамп.

Comment: Точно, Александр, похоже, что так и есть! Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В Нацкорпусе до 1900 года дано 195 примеров этой конструкции, например:

Одно из частных проявлений христианства ― мысль о том, что человечество может жить без рабства, хотя и включена была в идею христианства, ясно была выражена, **как мне кажется**, только у писателей конца XVIII столетия (Л. Н. Толстой).

Comment: Спасибо! Значит, я был неправ!) Но я прибавлю кое-что к своему вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то это по-русски и ничего новомодного в этом нет. Можно опустить слово "как".

"Мне кажется порою, что солдаты,
С кровавых не пришедшие полей..."

У этой конструкции опять же множество синонимов.

Comment: Как раз важно именно с "как"! А в примере у Вас "мне кажется" не вводная конструкция, а член предложения. Так что Вы неправильно поняли вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь опускается предположение, и оно из двух частей: *Если бы спросили* — как мне кажется, *то я бы ответил та*к. Естественно, с акцентом на МНЕ произносится.