# Многоточие в начале монолога

Tags: пунктуация, цитата, многоточие

Скажите, правильно будет поставить многоточие в начале, если я привожу монолог героя из фильма? Этот монолог — часть диалога, и я привожу его не с начала, но до конца. Это не важно, но этим монологом заканчивается и весь диалог.

Я хочу получить общий ответ и в то же время на всякий случай привожу детали конкретного примера, чтобы вы мне указали на нюансы, если вдруг они есть.

Comment: Либо монолог, либо не монолог.  Монолог не может быть частью диалога.

Comment: *Ну вы поняли.*

Comment: Я просто не знаю, как это ещё назвать.

Comment: «Случай привожу» — недопечатка?

Comment: *«Случай привожу» — недопечатка?* В смысле?

Comment: Не пропущено ли НЕ? Деталей конкретного примера нет вроде бы, да и самого примера тоже.

Comment: Нет, не пропущено. *И в то же время привожу детали* — сейчас добавлю для ясности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждое **цельное предложение** цитируемого автора или персонажа является самостоятельной цитатой и не требует постановки многоточия перед ним. Иначе мы почти везде видели бы эти три точки в начале предложения, взятого из середины абзаца или речи.

> *Пастернак писал: «Между тем изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок».*
>
> Но:
>
> *Пастернак писал: «...изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок».*
>
> *«...Изо всего искусства именно его происхожденье переживается всего непосредственнее, и о нем не приходится строить догадок», — писал Пастернак.* ([**Как оформлять цитаты?**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76) Грамота.ру)

Если же опускается одно или несколько предложений "внутри" цитаты, то многоточие заключается в угловые скобки: <...>.

[**8.5.4. Многоточие в угловых скобках**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091470.html)

> 1. *Полное предложение цитаты. <…> Полное предложение цитаты.*
> 2. *Первый абзац цитируемого текста.*
>    *<…>*
>    *Третий абзац цитируемого текста.*

Здесь ничего не сказано о пропуске предшествующих предложений. Вероятно, использование многоточия в начале цитаты (при условии, что она полная) не нужно. Я, например, никогда не сталкивался с таким:

*Он говорил: «<...> Это всё, что я хотел сказать».*

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Артём, только в вопросе нужно бы раздельно написать  _в начале_. И ещё видел в [одном вопросе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423586/Конструкция-как-мне-кажется), там три раза тоже слитно. Спасибо и Вам.

Comment: Я сначала так и написал, потом поправил. А почему считаете, что лучше раздельно? Тогда непонятно, в начале чего.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Если имеете в виду _сначала, сперва_, то слитно: _...правильно ли будет вначале поставить многоточие..._ Но всё-таки здесь речь идёт о начале предложения (цитаты), поэтому лучше дописать _в начале (чего)_. А в том вопросе явно нужно писать раздельно.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой У Розенталя: _Многоточие **в начале** текста указывает, что..._ (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=90) У Валгиной: _Многоточие ставится **в начале** предложения для..._ (http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-020.htm) Артём, предлагаю написать "многоточие в начале монолога".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, ну хорошо Римма, так и сделаю.))

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец: в каком том?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой На который я ссылаюсь в предыдущем комментарии (там осталось еще 2 _вначале_). А здесь еще в теле вопроса есть _вначале_ .

Comment: Там убедили, а тут всё нормально.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Я разобрался. Просто приписывал словам "вначале" и "сначала" дополнительное значение и специально не заглядывал в словарь в надежде, что кто-то из вас прямо мне скажет, что такого значения не существует (если это правда). Но теперь хорошая муха укусила и посмотрел. ;)